# How to check value exist or not when save in same model

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My table structure is like this:

```
id  school_id   grade_name  from_value  to_value    status
```

How I can check in same model that any value which is adding by user should not present in `from_value` and `to_value`.

`from_value` and `to_value` are my upper limit and lower limit fields, and I want to remain them unique in table rows.

Any idea guys..?

Comment: Pretty sure you need something better than checking for uniqueness here; you need to make sure that the ranges don't have any overlap. You'll presumably need to write your own validation function for this, perhaps using the `validateUnique` rule that @InigoFlores mentioned as inspiration.

Comment: If you solved your problem, then please add that as an actual answer (not as a comment) and accept it later on, so that the question appears resolved for future readers - thanks.

Comment: @ndm Done. (y), I wan't aware of this thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.x provides the `validateUnique` rule.

You can add the following rules:

```
$validator->add('from_value', 'unique', [
    'rule' => 'validateUnique',
    'provider' => 'table'
]);

$validator->add('to_value', 'unique', [
    'rule' => 'validateUnique',
    'provider' => 'table'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @InigoFlores and @ GregSchmidt for your help, but I solve my issue with general SQL Query which is `SELECT COUNT(*) AS from_val FROM table_name WHERE $this->request->data['from_value'] BETWEEN from_value AND to_value`